# Publish a file from an included project to App_Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc project (A) and this has a reference to another project (B) which includes a specific dll. I need this dll to be published to the app_data folder of any project which references project B.

I have tried setting it's build action, and the copy to output directory, but this doesn't seem to help. I've made sure the app_data folder exists on the server, and can publish files which are directly in the app_data folder of project A.

Comment: _"I have tried setting it's build action"_ Could you please show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

i have met this problem. I solve like that; move manually app_data files in publish folder. If App_Data folder exist in publish folder copy and paste from project to publish folder. If not exist create manullay.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the "copy to output directory" but note that will only put the dll in the bin output folder. However, from there you can copy it to App_data after the build: in the project properties, select the Build Events tab and add this to the post-build events (updating for your dll):

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)your.dll" "$(ProjectDir)App_Data\" /Y
```